# Возврат массива из функции (Си)

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Есть необходимость получить из функции массив с индексами определенных символов, например, 'a' со смещением (индексы начинаются с 1).
Смастерить массив получилось, но вот вернуть его не очень.

Где-то в main объявлены строка и указатель на массив
В переменной string массив символов. 
char* string = "abbla";
size_t* nums = malloc(...);

```
int* indices (const char* string, size_t* nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i) {
        switch (string[i]) {
            case 'a': 
                *(nums) = i + 1;
                printf("%c - %zu\n", string[i], *nums); // тут все ок
                break;
        }
    }


    return nums;
}
```

Ожидаемый результат: {1, 5} 
Полученный результат: {5, 0, -501312472, 32765, 2}

update:
Благодаря помощи уважаемых @LShadow77 и @avp код скорректировал:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* indices (const char* string, size_t* nums) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i) {
        switch (string[i]) {
            case 'a':
                nums[n] = i + 1;
                printf("%c - %zu\n", string[i], nums[n); // тут все ок
                n++;
                break;
        }
    }
     return nums;
}


int main() {
    const char* string = "abbla";
    size_t* nums = malloc(strlen(string) * sizeof(size_t));

    indices(string, nums);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(nums) / sizeof(size_t); ++i) {
        printf("%d %zu\t", i, nums[i]);
    }
}
```

printf в main возвращает "0 1".

Comment: Вы пишете все индексы в первый элемент массива. Добавьте перед циклом `int n = 0;` и замените `*(nums) = i + 1;` на `nums[n++] = i + 1;`. Перед return напишите также `nums[n] = 0;` (таким образом при использовании данной реализации вы сможете определить количество индексов в массиве-результате)

Comment: Да, тут, извиняюсь, моя ошибка. Но, если идти через итератор, у меня сегфолт. Решение где-то на поверхности и достаточно простое, но пока не поддается. И на выход нужен массив этих самых индексов.

Comment: Вы изменили код, как в моем комментарии и получаете segfault? Наверное что-то упустили. Измените код в вопросе так, чтобы его можно было скомпилировать и проверить

Comment: Да, нашел ошибку у себя, спасибо! Но результат пока все равно не совсем тот, что ожидалось.

Comment: Ну, так `sizeof(nums)` это размер указателя, а не выделенной в malloc памяти. Вы выделели в malloc `strlen(string)` элементов (столько индексов можно будет разметить в этой памяти). Сколько вы разместили в `indices()` неизвестно. Поэтому в ней перед return стоит написать `nums[n] = 0` (это будет признаком конца) и соответствующим образом скорректировать цикл в main

Comment: Спасибо, + Вам в карму. Попробую поправить и напишу по результату. Вообще через 20 лет после последней не совсем удачной попытки научится сложно даётся, хорошо, что есть сообщество.

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати, не забудьте выделить дополнительный элемент в nums под признак конца (на случай, если все в строке это `a`)/ Т.е. `malloc((strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(size_t))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря помощи @avp получилось следующее решение:
Необходимо было добавить счетчик вхождений искомого символа (n) в строку, его инкремент в теле switch и корректно выделить память под возвращаемый массив.

```
int* indices (const char* string, size_t* nums) {
    int n = 0;
    *nums = 0;
    int* indices = malloc(*nums * sizeof(*indices));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i) {
        switch (string[i]) {
            case 'a':
                indices[n++] = i + 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `int* indices = malloc(*nums * sizeof(*indices));` Чего?))) У меня плохие новости: данный код некорректен. Я уже молчу про то, что имя переменной `indices` совпадает с именем функции (не знаю, проглотит ли такое компилятор, но в любом случае так не следует делать).

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, нет смысла возвращать указатель на массив, который и так известен, ведь он передаётся в качестве параметра. Во-вторых, следовало бы возвратить вместо указателя размер получившегося массива индексов. В-третьих, помимо указателя на массив, а вернее на буфер, в котором формируется этот массив, следовало бы передать функции ещё и размер этого буфера, чтобы не допустить его переполнение. В четвёртых, после записи очередного индекса через указатель следует увеличить последний на единицу. Подытожу:

```
size_t indices (const char* string, size_t* nums, size_t nums_size) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < strlen(string)) && (count < nums_size); ++i) {
        switch (string[i]) {
            case 'a': 
                *nums = i + 1;
                printf("%c - %zu\n", string[i], *nums); // тут все ок
                ++nums;
                ++count;
        }
    }


    return count;
}
```

Вариант с динамическим массивом (возвращается указатель на массив):

```
//возвращает указатель на динамический массив индексов
size_t* indices (
        const char* string, //указатель на искомую строку
        size_t* nums_size   //указатель на переменную, в которую будет помещён размер массива
    ) 
{
    int len = strlen(string);

    //первый проход по строке - определяем размер массива
    size_t nums_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (string[i]=='a') ++nums_count;

    //создаём массив
    size_t* nums = (size_t*)malloc(nums_count*sizeof(size_t));

    //второй проход по строке - заполняем массив индексами
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (string[i]=='a')
        {
            nums[j++] = i + 1;
            printf("%c - %zu\n", string[i], i+1);
        }

    //возвращаем результат
    *nums_size = nums_count;
    return nums;
}
```

P.S. Не забываем потом удалить массив с помощью `free()`!

Comment: Спасибо. Но из функции необходимо вернуть именно массив с индексами вхождений, а не счетчик вхождений символа в строку или я не совсем хорошо разобрался в Вашем коде. Размер буфера не известен, но по условиям он динамический

Comment: @Ciuis Если по условиям массив динамический, то значит и создать его нужно динамически, и вернуть указатель на него. Однако размер этого массива тоже надо как-нибудь вернуть, т.к. в С++ нет способа узнать его, имея в наличие только лишь указатель. Я модифицировал ответ с новым вариантом.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но язык - Си, поэтому ни создание массива через new, ни дальнейшая очистка памяти через delete не сработают.

Comment: @Ciuis и что мешает вместо `new[]` использовать `malloc()`, а вместо `delete[]` `free()`?